# Bit masking and bit manipulation

Tags: c++

Let's say i have a byte sized variable like : unsigned char a = 0b0000'1111

and i turn on / off a certain bit using bit masking. I wanna know is this process of turning on / off slow for array of such unsigned char variables, for an array of size let's say like 20250000 etc

Comment: Why don't you benchmark it and find out? Also what do you mean by "slow"? Depending on how good your implementation is its likely to be almost the same as just iterating the array but then that O(n), is that fast?

Comment: Typically a processor has instructions for accessing array elements pretty much as fast as any other memory location (like a variable). But what may slow you down are cache misses when you try to access memory not sequentially, but randomly (by that I mean accessing different elements of the array that lay rather far away (more than 64 bytes away)

Comment: @Firefly oh got it, my bad! , Thanks for clarifying that it should be almost same as iterating an array

Comment: @AlexLarionov it's a 1d array, where each element is of type unsigned char and i just tend to loop through the array and change bit value for that particular byte.

i try to access sequentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be extremely fast to perform such an operation. Flipping bits in C++ would map to a relatively small amount of assembly code. There are x86 instructions to flip bits, so there is no reason for it to be slow.

With this said, If you are writing a bigger application, chances are high that somewhere else in your application will cause most of your slowdowns, rather than this basic bit flipping code. An example of this may be that your array will cause some cache misses (causing performance hits), or perhaps some prepossessing on the array will reduce your performance.

So even if this code is slow, there are probably ways to optimize your code to increase the performance. For example, instead of iterating over an array lineally, you could break the array up into chunks and perform calculations / bit flipping on those chunks in parallel using threads.